# Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' .. but doctor checks out ok

Tags: flutter, device

A new installation of flutter/dart went smoothly without issue .. running "flutter doctor -v" gives the following output:

```
 $ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.9, on Linux, locale en_AU.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 0.11.9 at /home/jedaa/bin/flutter
• Framework revision d48e6e433c (3 days ago), 2018-11-20 22:05:23 -0500
• Engine revision 5c8147450d
• Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
• Android SDK at /home/jedaa/bin/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native 
profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = /home/jedaa/bin/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /opt/android314/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136- 
b06)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
• Android Studio at /opt/android314
• Flutter plugin version 30.0.1
• Dart plugin version 181.5656
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136- 
b06)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
• IntelliJ at /opt/idea
• Flutter plugin version 30.0.2
• Dart plugin version 182.5124

[✓] VS Code (version 1.29.1)
• VS Code at /usr/share/code
• Flutter extension version 2.20.0

[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

and yet attempting to run the defalut starter app "flutter/material.dart" results in ... "Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components" ... irrespective whether i use Intellij or Visual Studio.

However,

```
$ flutter devices
1 connected device:

Pixel XL • HT69R0205363 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
```

I have searched the web and found similar complaints .. but no solution. I was hoping that someone might be able to throw some light on this as I am sure it must be something simple and straight forward.

Visual Studio is a new installation but I have been using Intellij now for 6 months on a daily basis and rarely have issue with it .. especially one that i cannot fix. :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Am I the only one that tried all of the answers and none worked?

Answer (score 11):

open Terminal in Android Studio or VS Code.

and writes this command :

```
flutter config --android-sdk <sdk-location>
```

SDK-location is your Path for SDK! for Example :

```
flutter config --android-sdk /home/sanaebadi/Pasport/programming/and_dev/sdk/sdk-tools-linux-3859397/
```

Comment: flutter config --android-sdk <sdk-location> ,sdk is in lower case

Comment: I test this command and is correct. maybe with lowercase is correct too

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem , then I tried this solution , and it helped me and my flutter app is running on my phone ..

all you need to do is install Android API level 29 (Android 9.0+ "Q")
go to Setting > Android SDK >SDK platform>Check Android 9+ and Press Apply button

I found this solution from github  .. her is the link .. 
Hope this help you

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22649#issuecomment-520472515

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, ensure that the API level of your Project SDK (File->Project Structure) <= of the API level of  your AVD.